# Balise <sup> is displaying like <sub> in react-native-render-html custom renderer

Tags: react-native-render-html

I'm using react-native-render-html to render html and the HTML  Tag is like a defines subscript text.

```
Au IV<sup>e</sup>
```

In my app :
[image: How is displaying]

I'm trying to have style to avoid that but I think there is better way to solve the issue.

What to you thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default style for `<sup>` element looks like this:

```js
{
  textAlignVertical: 'top',
  fontSize: 'smaller'
}
```

Unfortunately, there is a bug on React Native [whereby textAlignVertical: 'top' doesn't work for nested `Text` elements on Android.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30375)

[I've also submitted a feature request for `'sub'` and `'sup'` support in their Canny](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/support-superscript-and-subscript).

I suggest you:

- Upvote the Canny feature request;
- Upvote the bug report;

That would help giving more visibility to those issues. And if you or your team has any Android SDK experience, you could also submit a fix upstream. Check the bug report thread as a contributor seems engaged in resolving the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jules. I'll do what you suggested.