# React-native-render-html: how to render superscript or subscript text?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-render-html

Everything is rendered properly in my app, except the superscript and subscript texts.

I tried using `tagsStyles` to apply custom styles in `<sup>` and `<sub>` tags, but I could only change their `color` or `fontsize`. I couldn't get them to mimic superscript or subscript properties. `lineHeight`, `textAlignVertical`, `top` all these don't seem to work. Am I using those styles inappropriately?

Any workarounds? Any other library alternative to solve the problem? Anything will do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Balise <sup> is displaying like <sub> in react-native-render-html custom renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68136402/balise-sup-is-displaying-like-sub-in-react-native-render-html-custom-rendere)